# My budgerigar seems partially paralyzed, is breathing heavily, and is having problems standing. What should I do?

Tags: behavior, health, birds, budgerigar

I am really not sure what to do. My budgerigar has started behaving very suspiciously since noon. It looks like he has some kind of paralysis and I am really not sure what to do.

---

[image]

---

He has been looking like that for some period. He breathes regularly but heavily. He has problems with standing. Still, I saw him occasionally flying.

---

Please, I really don't know what to do.

P.S. I cannot go for a bird specialist vet, because unfortunately there is none in a radius of 100 km.

Comment: Has he flown into a window and hit its head possibly? I have seen birds behave *somewhat* similar after getting knocked out. A sad fact about my house is that with large windows on both sides of the house, during certain points of the day it looks like it can be flown through, I guess. The new curtains help a bit. =/

Comment: @Stian Yttervik My sister told me that she saw him possibly hit to head. Still he shared it off and was ok and after a while he was on bottom of cage.. Unfortunately he died sooner than I could do something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Budgerigars are common enough as pets that even a vet that isn't specialized in birds should have rudimentary knowledge. You should call any vet or pet clinic you find around you, describe the symptoms and ask if they would treat your pet. There's a chance they have an idea what's going on and you don't need to go to a specialist. And the initial phone call saves you a lot of money if they cannot treat him, and your bird a lot of stress.

I wouldn't let him fly around, just in case he gets symptoms during flight and crash lands.

Comment: Thank you for answer I appreciate it. Unfortunately he died sooner than I could come back to home from university .

Comment: @L.Diago I'm so sorry for your loss. I wish I could have done more for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your immediate task would be to try to comfort the bird, stroking the feathers, etc. because it is frightened and confused why this is happening. You want to prevent it from going into shock.

http://www.birds-online.de/gesundheit/gessonstiges/schlaganfall_en.htm

I found this website where it describes cerebral apoplexy which is a commonly called a stroke. Birds often lose motor control and suffer from paralysis of body parts controlled by specific areas of the brain where the stroke occurs. A vet is the only person you should have administer medication. And as stated, take measures to keep the bird from trying to fly, as that is their first instinct when they are frightened.

Comment: Thank you for answer I appreciate it.

Comment: @L.Diago Your welcome. I am sorry for your loss.